# Monitoring a file in real time

Tags: file, monitoring

I need a text file monitored in a way that the contents stay updated in a window on my screen - the contents of the text file will keep changing periodically and I want the display to update the changes ASAP.

Are there any programs out there (like `tail` for win32) that can help me achieve this? If not, could I perhaps write a script to that end?

Comment: There is also tail in OS X.

Answer (score 2):

Use

> tail -f

on the file. That will constantly update in the current window.