# How do I construct a terminal process that displays lines as they are added to a log file?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash

I'm needed to monitor a log file while I'm doing some debugging. The script I'm debugging writes to the terminal (STDIO) so having debugging info mixed in with that is annoying and I miss things.

What I would like to do is write my debugging info to a log file, simply appending each entry, and have a separate terminal window that is monitoring that file and displaying each entry as it is added.

Could I do something like:

```
echo << "=-EOF-="
```

where that somehow reads from the file and echoes each line until it encounters the magic termination string?

I have a feeling that this is possible, but I don't really know where to begin.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

I'm on 10.14 Mojave, so I'm using Bash

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Monitoring a file in real time](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101741/monitoring-a-file-in-real-time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ man tail

> [... elided ...]
>
> -f
> Don't stop when end of file is reached, but rather to wait for
> additional data to be appended to the input.
> (ignored if the standard input is a pipe, but not if it is a FIFO)
>
> -F
> The -F option implies the -f option, but tail will also check to
> see if the file being followed has been renamed or rotated.  The
> file is closed and reopened when tail detects that the filename
> being read from has a new inode number.  The -F option is ignored
> if reading from standard input rather than a file.

https://ss64.com/osx/tail.html